# Stars and Bars: Why An Alternate Approach Doesn't Work

Tags: combinatorics

From http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_stars-and-bars.html, suppose you have 7 cookies to distribute to 4 kids. Now, using stars and bars, we arrive at 10C3 (if you're choosing the 3 bars out of the 10 indices for the stars-and-bars string), or 10C7 (if we're instead choosing the stars). My question is why the answer $(4^7)/7!$ would not also be a valid approach? I understand that the two aren't numerically equal, and that the latter is incorrect, but I'm wondering what my error in reasoning is. For instance, if we imagine the kids as the letters A, B, C, and D, and the cookies as a 7-character string, then $4^7$, to me, seems to be the number of ways to assign the kids to each cookie such that the ordering matters (of which cookie gets assigned which kid mattering, and treating the cookies as distinct). Why, however, can we not then simply divide by $7!$, the number of ways to arrange those characters in a 7-character string, to yield our answer (where which cookie gets assigned to which kid not mattering, and thereby also making which cookie is which no longer be distinct)?
Perhaps it is a simple misunderstanding of ordering vs. distinction, but I'd still like to clarify, if possible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, $4^7/7!$ is not even a whole number!

The issue is that, for instance, the string $1122334$ has $\frac{7!}{2! 2! 2! 1!}$ reorderings, not $7!$. But the number of reorderings depends on the number of cookies each child gets (e.g., $1111234$ has $\frac{7!}{4!}$ orderings), so you cannot divide $4^7$ by a single number.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So as I believe I understand it, each quantity in the denominator is to make elements of the same "type" (i.e., like that are both 1's) not be distinct from each other (or really, have the order either appears not matter). Would that be correct so far?

Comment: For instance, if the above is correct, (such as dividing by 2! to make the two 1's not have their order matter from each other, and thus not be distinct), then I guess my question is then why we can't apply 7! instead in the denominator to make all the choices of kids not be distinct / as not having their order matter? I imagine this as the above 7-char string, where beneath each character is the cookie the kid is for. This treats the cookies as distinct. So I then imagine 4^7 as filling in the kids chosen, and then 7! as being able to make the cookies beneath them no longer be distinct.

Comment: @MishaReswick: Because just writing numbers doesn't mean you are doing the correct thing. There are $7!$ distinct ways that a string with $7$ distinct characters can be reordered; but there is only one way to write down a string of $7$ characters if they are all the same character. It's exactly the same reason why there aren't $6^2/2$ possible different rolls with two dice, but instead there are $\binom{7}{2}$.

Comment: @Arturo For a string all of the same character, however, could you not consider that as 7C7, of doing 7 x 6 x ... x 2 x 1 to place in the characters of the string, and then divide by 7!, the number of ways to rearrange them in that string? This also simply yields one.

Comment: @mreswick: No, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, and no. Why $7!$? You are just choosing **one** thing. Surely that should be $1^7$, not $7!$. Why are you doing $\binom{7}{7}$, when you were trying to do with with an exponential followed by a quotient? You are changing your argument to try to make it fit the answer, no wonder you keep getting the wrong answer when you don't know what the latter is!  When you calculate $4^7$, and then you try to divide by a single thing, you are assuming that *each* string appears the same number of times (the denominator). They **don't**.

Comment: @mreswick: again: roll two dice; first dice can fall in 6 ways; second in 6 ways. Order doesn't matter. So why is the answer to "how many different rolls are there" **not** $6\times 6/2!$? Because *some* rolls I get two ways (I can get a 5-6 by rolling a 5 first and a six second, or a six first and a 5 second), but **some** rolls I can only get one way (there is only one way to roll a double six). I can't just take $6^2/2!$. I need to separate out the doubles from the non-doubles. You would need to do the equivalent thing here. Which is way harder to do than with two dice.

Comment: @Arturo Thank you for your responses. I don't believe I am trying to change my "argument," only my misunderstanding. By saying 7C7, I believe I am using similar logic to what I asked earlier, with (4^7)/7!. With 7C7, I am filling in 7 possibilities, treating the objects distinct, and then dividing by 7! to make their order and therefore distinction no longer matter. Likewise, with (4^7)/7!, I am first filling in one of four possibilities for each character, and then trying to divide by 7! to make the order of all of those characters no longer matter, and hence which cookie, doesn't matter.

Comment: I realize this is incorrect, and thank you again for your detailed comments.

Comment: @mreswick: The problem is that when you say $7C7$, you are looking at only **one type of distribution**. But your "logic" before was supposed to be for **all** distributions at the same time. You can't do that. And we've told you **exactly** why your "logic" is utterly faulty. Instead of just repeating your reasoning, over and over and over, why don't you try to understand what we are telling you? You can't just divide by $7!$ because that assumes that *each and every* distribution occurs $7!$ times in your initial description. They *don't*.

Comment: @Arturo Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The stars and bars solution assumes the cookies are indistinguishable, and the only thing that matters is how many cookies each of the kids gets (the kids, however, *are* distinguishable). Note that if you number the cookies, it would be impossible in this distribution for kid B to receive a lower-numbered cookie than kid A.

Saying $4^7$ implies that the cookies are distinguishable; because it matters which kids is assigned cookie 1. So giving cookie 1 to kid A, and all other cookies to kid B result in a different distribution than giving cookie 2 to kid A and the remaining six cookies to kid B.

Okay, so let's say that you distribute them *as if* they were distinguishable, and then you want to divide by something to take into account the fact that they aren't. The thing is that $7!$ is not the correct way to do that, because it is not the case that each distribution of cookies is described in $7!$ ways. Again, consider the distribution of cookies in which $1$ cookie goes to kid A, and the remaining $6$ cookies go to kid B. How many times did you produce that particular assignment? Well, you didn't produce it $7!$ times, you only produced it $7$ times: once when kid A got cookie $1$, once when it was cookie $2$, once when it was cookie $3$, etc. But if it is the distribution that gives *two* cookies to kid A and the remaining five to kid B was produced $\binom{7}{2}$ times, not $7$.

The number of times each distribution is realized will vary depending on what the distribution is. It is not nearly as simply as just dividing by a fixed quantity, because each final distribution comes from a different number of ordered distributions.

That's why stars and bars is the better way of dealing with this problem.